# i give up what the formula for B2:B7 any one knows?

Tags: google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7ax3.jpg)

Hi im stuck more than 6 hours finding formula for this simple table, what the best formula for B2:B7 ? already use the filter-search, using vlookup also not work :

```
=filter(E:E,SEARCH(E2,A:A))
=VLOOKUP(A2;$D$2:$E$7;2;FALSE)
```

Please use the data on column D to show on column B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=index(RegexExtract(A2:A7,".*\s(.*)"))
```

Or this

```
=index(RegexExtract(A2:A7,"(?i)\b"&join("\b|\b",D2:D4)&"\b"))
```

The first formula extracts the last word, the second one extracts the first word in A2:A7 that matches *any* of the words in D2:D4.

Comment: the answer is correct but the position is not correct... how to correct the position ya ?? https://prnt.sc/26dxtdt

Comment: you don't have to drag it down. Enter it in B2 and it will automatically populate. Also, check my answer again, I added another option which I assume is what you are actually looking for.

Comment: Thanks it work, but I want the result based on the color data in column D, while your formula not using the color data on column D...

Comment: the second formula is the best,,, thank youu friend